# Generate .env.exmaple during docker compose in dist folder

Tags: node.js, typescript, docker, dockerfile

I want to generate an `.env` and and an `.env.example` file and push it to the docker image during the docker build with `Dockerfile`.
The problem is that the `.env.example` file is not copied to the docker image. I think it works with the normal env, because I copy the env.production and save it as an env.
However, I am using `node.js` and `typescript`. Most people know that there is a way to use env viriables in the code by generating an `env.d.ts` and `env.example`.
During docker compose i am getting unfortunately that error.

```
no such file or directory, open '.env.example'
```

apparently the env.example is not copied to the dist folder. I need this one though.

Dockerfile

```
# stage 1 building the code
FROM node as builder
WORKDIR /usr/app
COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm install
COPY . .
COPY .env.production .env
RUN npm run build
COPY .env.example ./dist


# stage 2
FROM node
WORKDIR /usr/app
COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm install --production

COPY --from=builder /usr/app/dist ./dist

COPY ormconfig.docker.json ./ormconfig.json


EXPOSE 4000
CMD node dist/index.js
```

.dockerignore

```
node_modules
```

docker-compose.yaml

```
version: "3.7"
services:
  db:
    image: postgres
    environment:
        POSTGRES_PASSWORD: postgres
        POSTGRES_USER: postgres
        POSTGRES_DB: postgres

    volumes:
      - ./pgdata:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
  web:
    build:
      context: ./
      dockerfile: ./Dockerfile
    depends_on:
      - db
    ports:
      - "4000:4000"
    volumes:
      - ./src:/src
```

Could somebody please help me !

Comment: Try setting a blank string for the empty keys ex. `PORT=''`. Also do you happen to use a .dockerignore file which can mess something like this.

Comment: I will ad my dockerignore one second please